# Why I am not getting total price correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

According to the problem statement, we need to input the quantity and price of the product then display the total price in the output
It is showing Parameter(id) is missing and wrong value for total price
What can be the probable reason for not showing the result

````
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="billcalc.css">
        <script type = "text/javascript">
         function calculateTotalPrice()
         {   pric=parseFloat(document.getElementById("price"));
             qt=parseInt(document.getElementById("qty"));
        
             res=pric*qt;
             
            document.getElementById(totalprice).innerHTML=res;
            return false;
         }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <h1>Bill Calculator</h1>
    <form onsubmit="calculateTotalPrice()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="productName">Product Name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="Product Name" id="productName" name="productName" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="price">Product Price in Rs.</label></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="Product Price" id="price" min="0" required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Quantity</label></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="Enter Quantity" id="qty" min="1" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="totalprice">Total Price in Rs.</label></td>
            <td><output type="number" id="totalprice" for="price qty"  required>
                
                
            </output></td>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="submit" ></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
   
      
    
    
    
</html>```
````

Comment: Forgot the quotes: `document.getElementById('totalprice').innerHTML=res;`

Comment: document.getElementById('price') => document.getElementById('price').value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you are missing the quotation marks around `totalvalue` in the following line:

```js
document.getElementById(totalprice).innerHTML=res;
```

it should be:

```js
document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML=res;
```

EDIT:
Currently you are trying to parse the Html node to a number. You have to use the `value` of the node.

```js
 pric = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
 qt = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty").value);

 res = pric * qt;
 document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = res;
 return false;
```

Remark: As you placed the result inside the form itself, it will be disposed right after submitting the form. You may want to consider placing it outside of the form.

EDIT 2:
If you want to stick with you current structure. You would need to remove the `id` of the submit button and add a return in the `onsubmit` clause.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="billcalc.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function calculateTotalPrice() {
        pric = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
        qt = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty").value);

        res = pric * qt;

        document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = res;
        return false;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <h1>Bill Calculator</h1>
  <form id="bill_from" onsubmit="return calculateTotalPrice();">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="productName">Product Name</label></td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Product Name"
            id="productName"
            name="productName"
            required
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="price">Product Price in Rs.</label></td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="Product Price"
            id="price"
            min="0"
            required
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Quantity</label></td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="Enter Quantity"
            id="qty"
            min="1"
            required
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="totalprice">Total Price in Rs.</label></td>
        <td>
          <output
            type="number"
            id="totalprice"
            for="price qty"
            required
          ></output>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! but I'm still facing the same problem. Is there any other reason?

Comment: I think I found the issue! Please have a look my Edit above and mark it as correct when it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks while entering the numbers but getting  'totalprice' component value calculation is wrong and in the description: "A required parameter (id) was missing. This error happens when a webpage expects a parameter to be passed from another page (by post or cookie), and it fails to do so. This happens sometimes when user session times out, due to inactivity, or when an URL that needs that mandatory parameter is instead directly typed in URL bar or invoked from browser bookmarks, like the SCORM Player page not being launched from a link in the course page." and that's why test cases are failing

Comment: Although the result is correct but soon after the result is displayed screen disappears and shows the above-mentioned comment.Big Thanks to you for putting in your efforts.

Comment: Im not sure about this error message but as i mentioned in my answer the result disappears as the tag containing the result is placed within the form itself. Therefore it will be reset just like the other fields when the form is submitted. You should consider placing it outside of the form or using the <output> tag as intended (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp).